# Returning current attribute name in QGIS Expression Dialog

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, features, expression

In Expression Dialog, I can use `$geometry` to returns the geometry of the current feature.

But how could I return the current attribute of the current feature? Something like `$attribute`.

The purpose of this question is to save the time finding the attribute name form "fields and values" list and click the attribute name multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following expression `attribute($currentfeature, 'field_name')` in the "Expression Dialog", see image below

[image: result]

> **In Record and Attributes**
>
> **Function attribute**
> Returns the value of a specified attribute from a feature.
>
> **Syntax**
> `attribute(feature,attribute_name)`
>
> **Arguments**
> `feature`         a feature
> `attribute_name`  name of attribute to be returned
>
> **Examples**
> `attribute( $currentfeature, 'name' )` → value stored in `'name'` attribute for the current feature

*Note:* Mind that `'field_name'` uses single quotation marks `'` a̲n̲d̲ n̲o̲t̲ `"`.

Comment: Is `attribute(feature,attribute_name)` equivalent to `attribute_name`? If so, it seems the  latter one is more concise. I'm still wondering if there's a way to skip inputting the `attribute_name` altogether?

Comment: What would you like to inputting instead of `attribute_name` while the attribute table can contain thousands of attributes and QGIS will not understand to which attribute you are refering to when using something like `$attribute` in comparison to `$geometry` which is a single object for each feature.

Comment: And yes, the `attribute($currentfeature, 'field_name')` is equivalent to `"field_name"`, you can check it with `if(attribute($currentfeature, 'field_name')  = "field_name", True, False)`